# Source Localization with the BLUE Estimator

Tags: matlab, estimation, array-signal-processing, localization, time-of-arrival

I'm trying to implement BLUE estimator in MATLAB for source localization and after my research I've come up with a theoretical example in Steven Kay's **"Fundamentals of Statistical Signal Processing: Estimation Theory"** book (Example 6.3).

In this solution, while estimating $\theta$, the Gauss-Markov theorem is used and a point called as nominal source position($R_{n_i}$) is defined rather than real source position($R_i$). There is equation which shows the relation between $R_{n_i}$ and $R_i$ found by first order Taylor series expansion.

I'm confused about finding the value of $R_{n_i}$ variable, can anyone explain me this solution?

This could be a very simple question, but I want to understand the theory and my mind is not clear now. When you look at the solution in the book, I think you will understand better than I wrote.

[image: Figure 6.3 from Kay.]

**EDIT:**

```
N = 8; %total number of receivers
var = 1;
c = 3*10^5; % speed of electromagnetic waves
x = [0 8 7 1 5 9 3 1]; %xi receiver location
y = [0 1 9 9 2 5 8 4]; %yi receiver location
xs = 3; ys = 6; %real source location
xn = 6; yn = 10; %nominal source location
Sxs = xs-xn; Sys = ys-yn;
for i=1:N
    R(i) = sqrt((xs-x(i))^2*(ys-y(i))^2);
    Rn(i) = sqrt((xn-x(i))^2*(yn-y(i))^2);
    co(i) = (xn-x(i))/Rn(i); %cosai
    si(i) = (yn-y(i))/Rn(i); %sinai
    noise(i) = var*randn(1,1); %e1,e2,..
end
for i=1:N-1
    e(i) = 1/c*(co(i+1)-co(i))*Sxs+1/c*(si(i+1)-si(i))*Sys+noise(i+1)-noise(i); %linear model (6.26)
end
H = 1/c*[co(2)-co(1) si(2)-si(1);
         co(3)-co(2) si(3)-si(2);
         co(4)-co(3) si(4)-si(3);
         co(5)-co(4) si(5)-si(4);
         co(6)-co(5) si(6)-si(5);
         co(7)-co(6) si(7)-si(6);
         co(8)-co(7) si(8)-si(7)];

A = [-1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0;
     0 -1 1 0 0 0 0 0;
     0 0 -1 1 0 0 0 0;
     0 0 0 -1 1 0 0 0;
     0 0 0 0 -1 1 0 0;
     0 0 0 0 0 -1 1 0;
     0 0 0 0 0 0 -1 1];
inaaT = inv(A*transpose(A));
estTheta = inv(transpose(H)*inaaT*H)*transpose(H)*inaaT*transpose(e); % eq. 6.27
```

This is not a modular code, I just want to be sure about not missing any point. However, when I run this code I get useless **estTheta** values. I think again I leave out something in the theory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem with your code is that the range calculations should be

`R(i) = sqrt((xs-x(i))^2`$\color{red}{\bf +}$`(ys-y(i))^2);`

`Rn(i) = sqrt((xn-x(i))^2`$\color{red}{\bf +}$`(yn-y(i))^2);`

But that doesn't appear to help.

The thing that seems to be the issue is that your noise variance is way too high.  If I set it to `var = 0.00000001` then I get good estimates.

The reason is because you're using this variance (or a standard deviation of 0.0001) to add noise to your `H` matrix. Looking at the values there:

[image: H matrix values]

you can see you're adding something with a variance of 1 (standard deviation of 1), to something of the order of $10^{-5}$.  That means your SNR (signal-to-noise ratio) is about -100dB.  I know of no algorithm that will help you at SNRs that low.

---

You left out that Kay defines
$$
R_i(x_s,y_s) = \sqrt{(x_s - x_i)^2 + (y_s - y_i)^2}
$$
and
$$
R_{n_i}(x_n,y_n) = \sqrt{(x_n - x_i)^2 + (y_n - y_i)^2}
$$
where $x_s = x_n + \delta x_s$ and $y_s = y_n + \delta y_s$.

Then the aim is to write $R_i$ in terms of $R_{n_i}$.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Taylor_series_in_several_variables) has an example of Taylor series in two variables, and the first order approximation is just:

$$
f(x,y) \approx f(a,b) + (x-a) \frac{df}{dx} (a,b) + (y-b) \frac{df}{dy} (a,b) + \ldots
$$

Then all you need to do is apply Wikipedia's expression to Kay's to get

$$
R_i \approx R_{n_i} + \frac{x_n-x_i}{R_{n_i}} \delta x_s + \frac{y_n - y_i}{R_{n_i}} \delta y_s. 
$$

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but how do I obtain xn and yn? I should use the xs=xn+δxs equation, then finding δxs is another blur thing for me.

Comment: Kay says: *This nominal position, which is close to the true source position, could have been obtained from previous measurements.*. The aim is to estimate $\delta x_s$ and $\delta y_s$.

Comment: I see, however, in estimation equation (6.27), there is a H matrix which consists of cos and sin values depends on xn, xi and Rni. Here, isn't xn independent of x(n-2), x(n-3) etc. or is xn a constant point? So, what refers to previous measurements exactly? Maybe, if it is possible you can give me the steps of a few iterations for calculating cos and sin values. Some further elaboration could be awesome for my side.

Comment: @sfwmonster : I'm not quite sure what you're asking. What is x(n-2) and x(n-2) ?

Comment: Sorry, let me clear that if the nominal position point is not a constant, I mean if we are sliding it to the real source position, then there will be more than one nominal position points which are at x_(n-1) point, x_(n+1) point etc. It's a better idea to ask only my question  that I just want to construct the H matrix depends on cos and sin values. For example if I calculate/estimate cosα_1 = (x_n-x_i)/R_ni, what values should I put instead of x_n and R_ni ?

Comment: OK. The subscript $n$ is not an index, it stands for ${\tt {\bf n}ominal}$. That was my confusion with x(n-2). There is only one nominal position: the location estimate at the previous time instant.  You already have the values $x_n$ and $R_{n_i}$. They are your current estimate of the $x$ location and the range.

Comment: I really feel stupid, unfortunately I'm still not able to see the values of xn and Rni. Yes, they are the current estimate, however, what is my current estimate? How do I start to estimate although H matrix depends on my estimate values?

Comment: @sfwmonster Usually, you start off with a guess.  And then apply the algorithm to update your guess.  Sometimes $(0,0)$ is as good a guess to start with as anything.  Sometimes $(10^6,10^6)$ is. Try it out and see what works in this particular case.

Comment: Your help is really appreciated. I will add my very simple Matlab code as an answer, if you can look at it please comment it for its correctness.

Comment: @sfwmonster That seems to do it.

Comment: That is a wonderful comment, but, just the final question :) What is the meaning of picking that kind of small variance?

Comment: @sfwmonster See update.